# MVC T4 Scaffold templates and annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, annotations, t4

Can you make custom annotations,something like

```
[MyAnnotation]  
public int Random {get; set;}
```

The reason I'm asking is I'm using T4 templates from Steven Sanderson Scaffolder and I'm trying to use my custom annotations so I can mark which property to scaffold and which not and many other things. Can I make my own annotations and how can I read them inside T4 file.

Thanks

EDIT:
I realised that my annotation should look something like

```
[MyAnnotation(some string)]
```

how can I check (in T4) to what is that string set for my annotation?

Comment: Yes you can create a class deriving from `ValidationAttribute` and override `isValid`

Comment: I learned how to make my own annotations but getting it's value in T4 is beyond my power :(